# .Net 4.0 WPF Application using Canon EDSDK Api experiencing high volume Out of Memory Errors

Tags: c#, wpf, out-of-memory, canon-sdk

my Net 4.0 Wpf photo booth application that uses the Canon EDSDK Api has been gradually becoming unusable due to constant Out of Memory errors like:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)

It happens a lot when the application captures and downloads the image from the camera to the computer and then attempts to crop the image to specific dimensions

Here is a snippet of where the most frequent crashes occur:

```
private void MainCamera_DownloadReady(EOSDigital.API.Camera sender, EOSDigital.API.DownloadInfo Info)
    {
        try
        {
            Info.FileName = "CamPic.jpg";
            string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            sender.DownloadFile(Info, dir); //Download image from camera to PC

            //Crop image to specific dimensions
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(() =>
            {
                PhotoObject ph;

                using (ImageFactory imf = new ImageFactory())
                {
                    imf.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\CamPic.jpg");
                    if (((WebcamImageVM)DataContext).IsPortrait)
                    {
                        imf.Crop(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(600, 0, 720, 1080));
                        ph = new PhotoObject(WebcamImageVM.GetBitmapSource(new Bitmap(imf.Image)), true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imf.Crop(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(150, 0, 1620, 1080));
                        ph = new PhotoObject(WebcamImageVM.GetBitmapSource(new Bitmap(imf.Image)), false);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogEvent(EventType.Error, "Failed to take photo with DSLR: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: whats ur question? do u want why this happens, where... etc

Comment: Hi, yes i would like to know why this is happening and what  should try to rectify the issue